# Best HTML5 Canvas Library to use for my scenario

Tags: open-source, library, html

We have been enrolled to make a web application that simply allows be to drag and edit text across an image which can then be converted and downloaded as JPEG or PDF (I will use a separate library for this). The data will also need to be saved to our server on an AJAX call. So my criteria for this library really is to make it as easy as possible to do the following -

1) Drag and edit existing text blocks over a high resolution image (will be exported at 300 DPI)

2) Make it possible to save the data to database so it can be recovered and editing resumed at any time.

I look forward to your thoughts and suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)

- Open source
- You can drag around, rotate, scale and edit text blocks
  A demo of the edit feature can be found [here](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/).
- Adding image backgrounds is possible.
  However, you would need to test whether Fabric.js and your favorite browser are capable of handling big images (as you described).
- Loading and saving canvas states is possible.
  See [here](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/) for an example.

  ---

  [image: Screenshot of Fabric.js in action]

  Image source: http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/ → 'SVG' tab → '41787 paths'

Comment: It is called `Fabric.js`. You should correct that typo.

Comment: @moose Nick Wilde just corrected it. You can simply suggest an edit (click 'edit') the next time and some people will hopefully approve corrections of typos.

Comment: @ComFreek This looks exactly what I need - thanks very much for the great library suggestion and fully considering my question.